# NameError in Model - search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a search with **Rails 4** - learning from a Rails cast (which is about version prior 3, apparently).
However, I get the following error:

> NameError in GamesController#index undefined local variable or method
>   `search' for #

This is my code

view:

```
<%= form_tag games_path, :method => 'get', :id => "games_search" do %>

   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>

<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def search
    @games = Game.search(params[:search])
end
```

model:

```
self.search(search)
 if search
  where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search}")
 else
  scoped
 end
end
```

migration:

```
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.date :releaseDate
      t.text :description
      t.integer :rating

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

routes:

```
  resources :games
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At which line did the `error` occurred?

Comment: at line 3 in the model: self.search(search)

Comment: Can you post `full error stacktrace`?

Comment: I am an idiot. I forgot the 'def' before self.search! Thank you so much for your effort!

Comment: LOl,even i didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Class Method**

I remember using that Railscast to help me create a search facility

What you're looking at is what's known as a [*class method*](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) - a method which initiates a class, and creates a response for you.

Here's how a `class method` should work in Rails (also consider each "model" is a `class`):

```
#app/models/game.rb
Class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.search(query)
      ... logic here
   end
end
```

I believe the problem you have is that you haven't declared `def` for your method, although I don't know for sure as you haven't posted your entire model code

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, i figured it out myself a second ago. Still going to accept your answer, for the trouble.

Comment: Thanks bud - hopefully my answer imparted some information about class methods for you too!

Comment: Even though the error is gone - how do I populate a view with results :S

Comment: How are you calling the method? Ajax or HTTP?

Comment: I eventually want to go Ajax, but I learning the basics first - so HTTP

Comment: another nooby -- the sql statement LIKE parameter -- ugh! So many things to learn with Rails.

Answer (score 1):

The model missed 'def'

```
**def** self.search(search)
 if search
  where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search}")
 else
  scoped
 end
end
```

I should be awarded the n00b badge. Sorry!